# I can't commit (your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master')

Tags: git

I created a project on gitlab and I added a user as developer, so my colleague clone the project correctly and he created a new file but when he try to commit with the following command :

```
git commit -a -m "update"
```

he got this message :

[image]

any explanation and help ?

Comment: Run `git add <file>` for untracked files before commit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after you do

- `git init`

if you want submit all of you file code just  type

- `git add .`

after that you can do

- `git commit -m "First commit"`

next ->

- > git remote add origin **remote repository URL**

in the end,

- `git push origin master`

hope it's help.

more useful reference -> [github docs existing project](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/)

Answer (score 2):

You have a new file in your project. For any new file, you need to add it by running `git add .`  and then run your commit message. `git commit -a` doesn't let you commit any new files that you haven't told git to track yet.