# Why I can't add nothing to my repository on github? Untracked files

Tags: git

I have problem with untracked files.

> On branch master
>   Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
>   Untracked files:
>     (use "git add ..."
>
> to include in what will be
>
> .metadata/
>
> Test/
>
> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

I was looking for answers anywhere but i didn't found anything. I visited these topics:

[Why does git status show branch is up-to-date when changes exist upstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828404/why-does-git-status-show-branch-is-up-to-date-when-changes-exist-upstream)
[I can't commit (your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605021/i-cant-commit-your-branch-is-up-to-date-with-origin-master)
[Why can I not commit? (Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master', no changes added to commit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703134/why-can-i-not-commit-your-branch-is-up-to-date-with-origin-master-no-change)

and nothing... Someone can help me?

Regards.
d.p

Comment: What exactly happens when you run `git add <file_path>` ?

Comment: Nothing, it's working when i run with path to this folder. But i dont wan to have in my repo this one and one more like .metadata

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Add` untracked files then `stash` the  changes.

```
$ git add .
$ git stash
```

If you have no important change in your local then, reset  `local/master`.with `remote/master`

```
$ git fetch
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: First hint ist working! Thx!
Second hint with hard reset is not the best because after reset I had the same problem how before hard reset .
Anyway, thank you so much!